# Issue with React Strap Alert box not closing individually

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I wanted to close each alert box when click on X close button of each, here all alert boxes closing together while single click, Please help

```
<Alert
        variant="danger"
        show={show}
        dismissible
        onClose={() => setShow(false)}
      >
        <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo</p>
      </Alert>
      <Alert
        variant="info"
        show={show}
        dismissible
        onClose={() => setShow(false)}
      >
        <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an Alert Message!</Alert.Heading>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo</p>
      </Alert>
      <Alert
        variant="info"
        show={show}
        dismissible
        onClose={() => setShow(false)}
      >
        <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an Alert Message !</Alert.Heading>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo</p>
      </Alert>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/alert-on-load-without-button-forked-gj59lj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are using the same `show` state for all three alerts, that's why when `show` change, all three alerts change too

One solution is to create an `AlertContainer` that wraps `Alert` and stores its own `show` state

```
const AlertContainer = ({ variant, children }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Alert
      variant={variant}
      show={show}
      dismissible
      onClose={() => setShow(false)}
    >
      {children}
    </Alert>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AlertContainer variant="danger">
        <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo</p>
      </AlertContainer>
      <AlertContainer variant="info">
        <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an Alert Message!</Alert.Heading>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo</p>
      </AlertContainer>
      <AlertContainer variant="info">
        <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an Alert Message !</Alert.Heading>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo</p>
      </AlertContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Alert on load without button (forked)]

Comment: good solution, but it only applies if you don't have to manage the state externally. In real life projects, you rather display Alerts on some event.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing one state for all Alerts. Create such a state, that can handle every Alert separately. For example give every Alert an id. Then create a state like this:

```
{ 
    1: true,
    2: true,
    3: true
}
```

Finally on close:

```
const handleClose = (alertId) =>
    setShow((prev) => { return { ...prev, [alertId]: false };
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/alert-on-load-without-button-forked-3j4d87

Comment: wanted without map individual alerts.

Comment: you can do it without map, if you want to. I just used a configuration object and map for the sake of simplicity

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/alert-on-load-without-button-forked-5jhmsk

Comment: @PRANAV is it helping?